Android .Net MAUI custom Splash screen not showing after deployment
My splash screen works correctly when debugging - showing the correct image and color, but after building for release and deploying it on Google Play, it loads the default purple background color with no image.  I have removed the default ".net" svg from the resources folder and added my own png.  It is like it is trying to use the original splash screen. Has anyone seen this?
<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.png" Color="#1B1E31" BaseSize="192,192" />
I am using VS 17.11.4 and always clean/rebuild before publishing.

Fixed by deleting bin and obj.  Apparently clean/rebuild was not enough.
